# Microsoft Translate Adding Extra Words To Translation

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

I am trying to translate to from English to Welsh.  I have a data set of 3032 sentences which I am aware is below the recommended 10000 limit but the issue is random words being added to sentences or added at the end of the translation.

With the dataset I have, I am getting a BLEU score of 94.25.

[Image of Translation Differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00GKx.png)

I have attached four examples where extra words are being added throughout the form.  At no point in the dataset is there duplication of words that match any of these formats and there is no trailing whitespace in the translations which would explain why "yn" in particular is appearing as a new sentence.

Is there any way of removing these erroneous extra words or increasing the accuracy of the translation?  To increase the overall amount of sentences to more than 10000 would be a very large task and would not be something to undertake if the system is still going to have a high chance of returning random words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also raised this as a support request with Microsoft.  They had said the issue was down to using a dictionary that included verbs as part of the translation.

I have since tried using English UK as the basis for the translation - an option that previously failed to build - and with the same dataset the BLEU score is 93.24 but the extra words have disappeared.

My issue has been resolved and it's now down to training out the incorrect translations.  It appears the English to Welsh translation has a bug.